# Pop up and overlay page

Tags: java, function, popup, load, innerhtml

I have created a pop up page with an overlay (seperate page loads into div), but my option to close out of the pop up isn't showing up.

Here is the link for the pop-up window:
http://jymeross.com/project5.html

How do I get the close window (.cancel class) to appear? The "X" link is currently only showing here:
http://jymeross.com/project5.html#loginScreen

Here's the code

```
<head>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="slider1.css" type="text/css" charset="utf-8" />

<style type="text/css">
.button
{
    width: 150px;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: #FF8C00;
    box-shadow: -8px 8px 10px 3px rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
    font-weight:bold;
    text-decoration:none;
}
#cover{
    position:fixed;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    background:rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    z-index:50;
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    display:none;
}
#gallery
{
    height:525px;
    width:675px;
    margin:0 auto;
    position: relative;
    z-index:100;
    display:none;
    border:5px solid #cccccc;
    border-radius:10px;
}
#gallery:target, #gallery:target + #cover{
    display: block;
    opacity:2;
}
.cancel
{
    display:block;
    position:absolute;
    z-index:100;
    top:3px;
    right:2px;
    height:30px;
    width:35px;
    font-size:30px;
    text-decoration:none;

}
</style>


</head>

<body>


<br><br>
<div align="center">
<a href="#gallery" onclick="load_project1()" class="button">View Gallery</a>

</div><!--close center-->


<div id="gallery">
    <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
 </div><!--close gallery-->

<div id="cover">
</div>

<script>

    function load_project1() {
     document.getElementById("gallery").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" width="575" height="325" data="project1.html"></object>';
     }

</script>


</body>
```

Comment: what javascript library have you used for this popup? Is this about css bug or js but? Will you specify what you did to accomplish what, and what is not working so far?

Comment: I'm using CSS for the pop-up. Within the pop-up, when I added the script at the bottom to load another html page within in the pop-up div, which is when I lost the .cancel class ("x" to close the popup).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make the sub div under the gallery, and then load the content to the div.

```
<div id="gallery">
  <a href="#" class="cancel">&times;</a>
  <div id="gallery-body"></div>
</div>


function load_project1() {
     document.getElementById("gallery-body").innerHTML='<object type="text/html" width="575" height="325" data="project1.html"></object>';
     }
```

Then you will keep close link there.